# Creating 2-D list in python using random numbers.

Tags: python

```
import random

rows = 3
cols = 3 
virus = [0,0,0,0,0,1,2]
virus_level = random.choice(virus) 
first_gen = []
row =[]
for rownum in range(rows):
    for colnum in range(cols):
        virus_level = random.choice(virus)
        row.append(virus_level)
    first_gen.append(row)
```

I need to create a 2-D list using the random numbers from the list virus. This is what I have so far, the numbers aren't in random order and the list prints out as a 9 by 3, not 3 by 3. Some pointers in the right direction would be nice.

Comment: You probably need to reset `row` to `[]` after you append it to `first_gen`

Comment: Are you trying to `reshape` a 1D list into a 2D list? The virus list has 7 numbers, whereas a 3x3 list would have 12 numbers.

Comment: row=[] should definitely be inside the first for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset `row` on every loop.

Taking your code snippet as-is, if you just take the `row =[]` line and put it inside of the outer loop, that should give you the right results.

```
import random

rows = 3
cols = 3 
virus = [0,0,0,0,0,1,2]
virus_level = random.choice(virus) 
first_gen = []
for rownum in range(rows):
    row = []    
    for colnum in range(cols):
        virus_level = random.choice(virus)
        row.append(virus_level)
    first_gen.append(row)

print first_gen  # [[2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment to `row[]` should be inside the outer-most loop, like so:

```
import random

rows = 3
cols = 3
virus = [0,0,0,0,0,1,2]
virus_level = random.choice(virus)
first_gen = []
for rownum in range(rows):
    row = []
    for colnum in range(cols):
        virus_level = random.choice(virus)
        row.append(virus_level)
    first_gen.append(row)
```

However, I prefer using list comprehensions for these sorts of things. Here is an alternative:

```
from pprint import pprint
import random

rows = 3
cols = 3
virus = [0,0,0,0,0,1,2]

first_gen = [[random.choice(virus) for _ in range(rows)] for _ in range(cols)]
pprint (first_gen)
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
>>> import random
>>> rows=3
>>> cols=3
>>> virus=[0,0,0,0,0,1,2]
>>> [[random.choice(virus) for r in range(rows)] for c in range(cols)]
[[0, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```